# Using Navigation Drawer as sliding menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to use navigation drawer as sliding menu. Like I wanted to do several operation on one activity. Suppose there is a Student Database and I want to create,read,update,delete student. Each operation can be done in one activity by selecting menu item.

I have searched a lot but there is only solution on creating navigation drawer using multiple activities or fragments. How should I do this? Or is there a better alternative solution?

Comment: This is both broad and unclear what you're asking. Are you having trouble with something specific? You can create a Navigation Drawer activity in Android Studio using the given templates, that might help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

If i right unerstand you, you want something like swipe ListView.
You can use, for example, this lib: [SwipeMenuListView](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `helper` class containing method to update,delete,create,read the database. 
create the navigation drawer and use `listview` containing items or simply buttons for creating,updating,deleting,reading etc.
then handle the Click of that `listview` items or buttons. In case of listview you require `onItemClickListener`() whereas you can add `onClickListener`() for buttons.

Inside these methods, call your required methods which you created in helper class. for example. if you created a button for creating student, then the `onClickListener`() should contain method to create student from helper class.